# Can I use "being + Past Participle" instead of "have been + PP"?

Tags: usage, passive-voice, construction

I've came across some sentences that I think have been reduced from "have been + [past participle]" to "being + [past participle]" but I don't know whether this right or not and I couldn't find any grammar topic about this.

This is one of those sentences:

> There seems to have been a spate of this substance being used recently.

Comment: Could you say how you would expect your sentence to appear if "unreduced"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach guess must've used another sentence something like: The new Town Hall, which has been designed by TMC Architects Ltd, is expected to receive several awards==The new Town Hall, being designed by TMC Architects Ltd, is expected to receive several

Comment: With the example you give in the question, are you comparing with 'There seems to have been a spate of this substance having been used recently'? I don't think many practised Anglophones would use 'having been used' here; time sequencing doesn't demand the clarification of the  more complex structure. But then 'The use of this substance seems to have increased greatly in recent months' is more idiomatic.

Comment: *a spate of this substance being used* is natural "generic" phrasing, where *...of this substance **having been** used* implicitly calls attention to ***a number of recent incidents / detections** of this substance [mis]use*. Someone who works in judicial / social services might choose to use Present Perfect Continuous because they tend to *think* in terms of countable instances. Indeed, the very word ***spate*** in the example is consistent with that perspective, which won't shared by others who think of substance abuse as they do air pollution (it's *everywhere*, not *isolated incidents*).

Answer (score 1):

> The new Town Hall, designed by TMC Architects Ltd, is expected to receive several awards.

Is the reduced equivalent of

> The new Town Hall, which has been designed by TMC Architects Ltd, is expected to receive several awards.

And in both cases “The new Town Hall” is qualified by a non-defining clause. Non-defining clauses can be omitted and are de-emphasised.

However, in

> The new Town Hall, being designed by TMC Architects Ltd, is expected to receive several awards.

“being designed by TMC Architects Ltd” = **because it has been designed** by TMC Architects Ltd and is probably best classed as a subordinate clause of reason.